# LINQ to XML - Get element based on a nested elements value

Tags: c#, linq

I want to select an element within my XML based on the value of a nest element.

Here is an example of the XML:

```
<Agents>
    <Agent ID="xxx">
        <Login>xxx</Login>
        <Password>xxxx</Password>
        <Products>
            <Product ID="zzz">
            </Product>
        </Products>
    </Agent>
</Agents>
```

Here is my first attempt at a LINQ query:

```
var DetailsOfUserAccount =
  from agent in policySpecificationXml
        .Descendants("Agent")
        .FirstOrDefault(p => (string)p.Attribute("ID") == productId)
        .Descendants()
  select new
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you be more clear in your question? What is the result you're expecting? How can we help you if you just give us your first attempt without specifying what's wrong with you attempt?

Comment: Sorry mastoj. Basically if I had many agent nodes I wanted to select the agent that contains a Product nodes with a Product ID using only the Product ID to search with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely clear, but sounds like you want something like...

```
var detailsOfUserAccount = policySpecificationXml
    .Descendants("Agent")
    .Where(agent => agent.Descandants("Product")
                         .Any(product => (string)product.Attribute("ID")
                                             == productId))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```